# any idea what fractal algorithm might generate this shape?

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms, fractals, image-processing

I Found this image around, and i'm curious what algorithm generates this kind of shape

[image]

In particular, i'm curious how the flow lines are generated, since usually the Mandelbrot iteration just generates different regions depending on the steps required to get into divergence

Comment: nice, where did you find it?

Comment: a facebook page called Emotional State

Comment: Have you seen the Burning Ship?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Burning_Ship_Left.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm maybe external argument / field lines :

http://fraktal.republika.pl/cpp_argphi.html

http://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/phase/phase.html

See also external ray in wikipedia

or triangle inequility

http://jussiharkonen.com/?page_id=65

www.ultrafractal.com/help/index.html?/help/coloring/standard/triangleinequalityaverage.html

Nice image. Where did you find it ?

Comment: a facebook page called Emotional State

Comment: I have googled Emotional State facebook. I did not find it. Can you place a link ?

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/EmotionalState/149528535086983